# Select roads that are between FROM and TO

Tags: oracle, select, oracle-12c, parameter, where

I have a `road` table:

```
 create table road
   (road_id int, 
    name_ nvarchar2(15), 
    from_ nvarchar2(15), 
    to_ nvarchar2(15), 
    sort int
   );
insert into road (road_id,name_,from_,to_,sort) values (4,'Street A','Street 1','Street 2','1');
insert into road (road_id,name_,from_,to_,sort) values (6,'Street A','Street 2','Street 3','2');
insert into road (road_id,name_,from_,to_,sort) values (5,'Street A','Street 3','Street 4','3');
insert into road (road_id,name_,from_,to_,sort) values (3,'Street B','Street VI','Street VII','600');
insert into road (road_id,name_,from_,to_,sort) values (7,'Street B','Street VII','Street VIII','700');
insert into road (road_id,name_,from_,to_,sort) values (1,'Street B','Street VIII','Street IX','800');
insert into road (road_id,name_,from_,to_,sort) values (2,'Street B','Street I','Street II','100');
insert into road (road_id,name_,from_,to_,sort) values (9,'Street B','Street II','Street III','200');
insert into road (road_id,name_,from_,to_,sort) values (11,'Street B','Street III','Street IV','300');
insert into road (road_id,name_,from_,to_,sort) values (8,'Street C','Street X','Street Y','9');
insert into road (road_id,name_,from_,to_,sort) values (10,'Street C','Street Y','Street Z','10');
commit;
select * from road order by name_, sort;

   ROAD_ID NAME_           FROM_           TO_                   SORT
---------- --------------- --------------- --------------- ----------
         4 Street A        Street 1        Street 2                 1
         6 Street A        Street 2        Street 3                 2
         5 Street A        Street 3        Street 4                 3

         2 Street B        Street I        Street II              100
         9 Street B        Street II       Street III             200
        11 Street B        Street III      Street IV              300

    {Gap in Street B}

         3 Street B        Street VI       Street VII             600
         7 Street B        Street VII      Street VIII            700
         1 Street B        Street VIII     Street IX              800

         8 Street C        Street X        Street Y                 9
        10 Street C        Street Y        Street Z                10
```

Eventually, [I would like to make a tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256420/search-and-zoom-to-street-stretch-by-name-from-to) that allows users to select roads between a `from_` and a `to_` (the values would be entered in parameters).

To do this, I think I need to make a query that can do something like:

Select roads where the `name_` is **Street B**, between **Street II** and **Street VIII** (inclusive).

```
   ROAD_ID NAME_           FROM_           TO_                   SORT
---------- --------------- --------------- --------------- ----------
         9 Street B        Street II       Street III             200
        11 Street B        Street III      Street IV              300
         3 Street B        Street VI       Street VII             600
         7 Street B        Street VII      Street VIII            700
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select *
from road
connect by (prior to_ = from_ and from_ != 'Street V')
start with name_ = 'Street B' and from_ = 'Street II'
;

   ROAD_ID NAME_      FROM_      TO_              SORT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         5 Street B   Street II  Street III        200
         6 Street B   Street III Street IV         300
         7 Street B   Street IV  Street V          400
```

Answer for the updated question:

```
select road_id, name_, from_, to_, sort
from
(
  select road_id, name_, from_, to_, sort, 
  row_number() over (order by sort) as rn from road
  where name_ = 'Street B'
)
connect by (prior rn + 1 = rn and from_ != 'Street VIII')
start with from_ = 'Street II'
;

   ROAD_ID NAME_           FROM_           TO_                   SORT
---------- --------------- --------------- --------------- ----------
         9 Street B        Street II       Street III             200
        11 Street B        Street III      Street IV              300
         3 Street B        Street VI       Street VII             600
         7 Street B        Street VII      Street VIII            700
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution. Thanks. In a perfect world, where streets were laid out in an clean hierarchical manner, then this would work just fine. However, in reality, streets stop and start (have gaps) and lots of other weird stuff happens. Unfortunately, the hierarchy of the `FROM` and `TO` cannot be relied upon. This is where the `SORT` field comes in. Would you be willing to provide an alternative answer that uses `SORT`, rather than the hierarchical nature of `FROM` and `TO`? I've updated the `DDL` to reflect this challenge.

Comment: @Wilson Updated.

Answer (score -1):

This works, but I imagine there is a more elegant way to do it.

```
SELECT 
    road_id
FROM 
    road
WHERE 
    name_= [Enter a street name:] 
    AND sort Between 
                (select
                    sort
                from
                    road
                where
                    name_ = [Enter a street name:]
                    and from_ = [From:]) 
                and 
                (select
                    sort
                from
                    road
                where
                    name_ = [Enter a street name:]
                    and to_ = [To:]);
```

It's an local MS Access query with parameters.

Comment: This query fails if there are duplicate records (the `WHERE` clauses in the subselects are only supposed to return a single row). I've haven't checked Balazs' query for this issue yet.

Comment: This question was tagged as an Oracle database; sure you could use MS Access to "access" the Oracle database, but what if end users don't have MS Access?

Comment: @MarkStewart - It's just a mock up of a query with parameters. It was my original attempt to answer my own question, but I suspected that there might be a more elegant way to do it. Hence why I asked the question in the first place. **I don't think it warrants a down-vote.**

Comment: Sorry;good point; I tried to undo the down-vote and got locked out....